# Equal Height Binning on Spark

Tags: apache-spark

I am trying to implement equal height binning in *Spark*. The main issue I am facing is that my implementation is linear and not scalable.

I have thought of an approach, but I think my design is very inefficient:

First, I sort the dataset on the basis of the column on which binning has to be done. I then send it to a function which assigns the bin number to a particular value.

Can someone please suggest how to approach this problem from a different point of view?

```
  anim    wt
1     1 181.0
2     2 179.0
3     3 180.5
4     4 201.0
5     5 201.5
6     6 245.0
7     7 246.4
8     8 189.3
9     9 301.0
10   10 354.0
11   11 369.0
12   12 205.0
13   13 199.0
14   14 394.0
15   15 231.3
```

After binning (equal height) the "wt" column should be assigned a bin value as under.

```
anim    wt wt2
1     1 181.0   1
2     2 179.0   1
3     3 180.5   1
4     4 201.0   2
5     5 201.5   2
6     6 245.0   2
7     7 246.4   3
8     8 189.3   1
9     9 301.0   3
10   10 354.0   3
11   11 369.0   3
12   12 205.0   2
13   13 199.0   1
14   14 394.0   3
15   15 231.3   2
```

The program should basically sort the dataset on basis of wt's value and then divide it into bins, taking equal number of elements into each bin.

Comment: Can you give an input/output example?

Comment: @DanielL.Added an example. Thanks !!

Answer (score 0):

This is a hard question indeed. There are not that many ways to sort efficiently and fewer can be easily distributed. I imagine you should be able to do something similar to Merge-Sort, say, by dividing your set of N entries until you get chunks of N/K entries, which you then sort and divide into K buckets. The merge operation could then be a 1-pass and if at any point the size of a bucket exceeds N/K, you "spill" to the next bucket (also sorted, so always a prepend).

In principle, knowing the numbers N and K then the size of a bucket should be easy to compute. As Spark goes, you might want to look into Sort-Based Shuffling ([here](http://databricks.com/blog/2014/11/05/spark-officially-sets-a-new-record-in-large-scale-sorting.html) and [here](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-2045)), where I understand the maintainers have gotten significant improvements (and made significant optimizations). It might be as simple as partitioning using this tool into K partitions! :-)